How to combine these LINQ queries and will it be 3X faster?
I've been optimizing some badly written LINQ queries.  I used to iterate over an IQueryable "Items" which was causing the queryable to go to list and slow things down a bit (return all records).  I ended up with this code which was noticeably faster:
  IQueryable<InventoryItem> Items;
 
      Items = from m in _context.Inventory.Where(m => m.Removed == 0)
              select m;
      //  various filtering happens...

     int ItemsCount = await Items.CountAsync();
     int TotalQTY = await Items.SumAsync(s=>s.IntegerQuantity);
     decimal TotalPrice = await Items.SumAsync(s => s.IntegerQuantity * s.ApproximateCost);
            
     InventoryTotals inventoryTotals = new()
     {
         TotalQuantity = TotalQTY,
         NumberOfItems = ItemsCount,
         TotalApproximatePrice = TotalPrice
     };

My question is how to combine those three LINQ statements, and if I do, will it be faster? 3 times the speed?

What is Items And where does it come from? Also: have you tried Aggregate Linq ?

It's an IQueryable... I'll add it.

Group by constant is your answer.

@Svyatoslav Danyliv, yes, I think that does answer it.  I'll do my own benchmarks to test.

You can try doing the sums in one query using GoupBy:
var results = Items.GroupBy(s => 1)
     .Select(g => new InventoryTotals {
        NumberOfItems = g.Count(),
        TotalQuantity = g.Sum(s=>s.IntegerQuantity),
        TotalApproximatePrice = g.Sum(s => s.IntegerQuantity * s.ApproximateCost)
      })
    .First();


I just used  InventoryTotals inventoryTotals = Items.GroupBy... and it worked straight off the bat.  Doing some benchmarking now... I think it's about 2x faster.

Strangely enough it's slower if it's the first request.  Then faster for subsequent ones... ?  (I'm benchmarking in local IDE environment)

So using the 3 lines (original version) it's taking 39 milliseconds on first request, then 23, 17, 17, 17.  Using this version it's taking 73 milliseconds for first request, then 6, 8, 7, 15.  ???

It all depends on how good the SQL query is that it generates. Sometimes doing it in separate queries is faster. Most likely SQL is reusing the plan it generates after the first run, but the question is is it still faster if you change the in;put parameters?

I added a search term and a warehouse filter, and now the 3 line versions first request was slower... so that one was 123, 97, 94, 92... with this one-line solution it was 102, 42, 40, 31... so with more parameters this one-liner is definitely faster.

adding await and FirstAsync() has a small effect but just like a millisecond faster, so not measurable/conclusive.  I wanted to keep this async all the way through though, so I added that.

I don't understand why this is any different from the OP's code. It's still doing three iterations of the entire data PLUS it's added a useless grouping.

It's probably only faster because you aren't waiting for 3 rounds of network packets. This will result in one sql statement and one round trip to the server. If the database was very slow to calculate your 3 queries, you likely wouldn't notice the extra network delay. The first request is likely slower because EF has to compile and cache your query, from an Expression tree to sql and a materialisation function on first use.

@browsermator Benchmarking in the IDE is not a good idea.  Too much overhead.  And the model is not materilaized until the first query is submitted, leading to the first request being slower.  I'd suggest benchmarking in a console app, and create an initial warmup query to materialize the model before your benchmarking queries.
